# How to schedule code to run at a specific time every day?

Tags: python, automation, scheduling

Need help to run code that automatically starts at 4:30pm every day on Python Visual Studio Code. I don't want to print anything I just want to execute my commands like: `pg.keyUp('enter')`.

For example.

```
import schedule
import time

def job():
    pg.keyUp('enter')                    < This no work

schedule.every(60).seconds.do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Only works with printing text.

Comment: you can use cron job. Also you can achieve using Windows Scheduler.
Step-1 : Create Python Script to run 
Step-2: Use Windows Scehduler to configure you job.
Step-3: Seat back and enjoy.

Comment: `pg.keyUp('enter')` looks like its sending a keyboard command.

I'm not too sure about this, but scripts running in the back, may not have access to the IO. 

Try it with a cronjob or windows scheduler first, or else you'll have to share more information about what the purpose and end goal is here.

Comment: I use a mac and can't use windows scheduler. I'm trying to automate keyboard tasks on my computer.  I needed something that could control my other stretch of code. Cronjob was my next choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use crontab to run the script at 16:30 every day.

```
30 16 * * * /usr/bin/python script.py
```

Change script.py to the full python file location

Here is a guide on how to use crontabs

https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-schedule-python-scripts-with-cron-the-only-guide-youll-ever-need-deea2df63b4e?gi=36e3b90594a4

Answer (score 0):

Using Task Till Dawn, I was able to schedule a python script to run on Windows. It looks like it should work on a mac too according to their [downloads](https://www.oliver-matuschin.de/en/downloads/). Here are the steps I took:

- first, I set up a batch file in Notepad++ (or some program which can save to *.bat) with the path to your python executable + " " + your script in paranthesis

`"C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/envs/py37/pythonw.exe" "C:/pathto/test.py"`

- open Task Till Dawn and create a new task
- Actions tab > Files and folders > Specify files and folders > this is where you add the *.bat file
- Actions tab > Files and folders > Open applications files and folders
- Schedule tab > set time interval
- Save and close

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I use a 3rd-party software called Task Till Dawn. I believe it's open-sourced, and it works really well.

Comment: Can you provide details on how you do this with Task Till Dawn?